# jQuery Ajax - Displaying download dialog when content type is 'application/pdf'

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using TCPDF in my CakePHP project to generate PDF files based on user input and results based on their inputs. Currently, I'm sending the user inputs to a stand-alone `.php` file via Ajax. The stand-alone `.php` file generates a PDF file based on the data sent, and then returns a PDF file, as shown in the [TCPDF examples page](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php).

Everything works fine when I directly access the stand-alone .php file (I get a download file prompt from the browser), but when I try it via Ajax, I'm unable to replicate the same behaviour. TCPDF takes care of setting up the correct headers, so I reckon this is an issue with my jQuery. Below are my different, but unsuccessful attempts:

```
//attempt 1
$.ajax({
  url: '/download.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: { type: 'generate', values: $('#table').html() },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response); //outputs garbled binary data on the browser console
  }
});

//attempt 2
$.ajax({
  url: '/download.php',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'text',
  data: { type: 'generate', values: $('#table').html() },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response); //outputs empty string ""
  }
});

//attempt 3
    $.ajax({
  url: '/download.php',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'text',
  contentType: 'application/pdf',
  data: { type: 'generate', values: $('#table').html() },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response); //outputs empty string "", same as above. No download dialog.
  }
});

//attempt 4
    $.ajax({
  url: '/download.php',
  type: 'post',
  contentType: 'application/pdf',
  data: { type: 'generate', values: $('#table').html() },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response); //outputs empty string "", same as above. No download dialog.
  }
});
```

How can I force the browser to show the download dialog to the user while using Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with just AJAX.
If you can download the file via a link, you can just set the location of the page to it

```
window.location.href = link;
```

Comment: This could work if I saved the generated PDF file to disk. But I want to discard it as soon as the user download is complete. I figured out a very inelegant way to achieve what I wanted. Feel free to improve it if you have a better idea!

Answer (score 0):

I found a very ugly, but convenient, way to accomplish this. The trick is to create a pseudo-form, append all variables that need to be passed to the pdf generator file in hidden `input`s, and submit it via javascript/jQuery. This would ensure that the current page state is not affected, and at the same time, will also receive the output of the pdf generator with all the correct headers set, resulting in a browser download dialog.

For anyone who might have a similar problem, following is a sample code:

```
$('body').append('<form id="generate_pdf" method="post" action="/generate.pdf"></form>');
$('#generate_pdf').append('<input type="hidden" name="values" value="' + val_1 + '">');
$('#generate_pdf').append('<input type="hidden" name="location" value="Mordor">');
$('#generate_pdf').submit();
//as long as generate.pdf has correct headers set, TCPDF will do its thing and a download dialog will be shown by the browser once it returns, all inside the current page.
```